# open camera from a service getting error

Tags: android, android-camera

I have an activity which is starting a service in that service I try to capture an image 
and save it to sd card.Original code source is here tell me what's  wrong http://easyandroidtutorials.blogspot.in/2012/09/capture-image-without-preview-as.html

**Error**

```
07-04 08:24:41.579: D/Camera(3036): app passed NULL surface
```

**From activity**

```
Intent service = new Intent(context, CameraService.class);
    context.startService(service);
```

**Service Code**

```
public class CameraService extends Service
{
//Camera variables
//a surface holder
private SurfaceHolder sHolder; 
//a variable to control the camera
private Camera mCamera;
//the camera parameters
private Parameters parameters;
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate()
{
    super.onCreate();

}
@Override
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onStart(intent, startId);

    mCamera = Camera.open();
    SurfaceView sv = new SurfaceView(getApplicationContext());


    try {
        mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(sv.getHolder());
        parameters = mCamera.getParameters();

        //set camera parameters
        mCamera.setParameters(parameters);
        mCamera.startPreview();
        mCamera.takePicture(null, null, mCall);

    } catch (Throwable e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    //Get a surface
    sHolder = sv.getHolder();
    //tells Android that this surface will have its data constantly replaced
    sHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
}



Camera.PictureCallback mCall = new Camera.PictureCallback()
{

    public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera)
    {
        //decode the data obtained by the camera into a Bitmap

        FileOutputStream outStream = null;
        try{
            outStream = new FileOutputStream("/sdcard/Image.jpg");
            outStream.write(data);
            outStream.close();
        } catch (Throwable e){
            Log.d("CAMERA", e.getMessage());
        } 
    }
};


@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A service is meant for tasks that should be executed in the background. You cannot launch a camera inside a service as camera will need a preview surface.

Comment: http://easyandroidtutorials.blogspot.in/2012/09/capture-image-without-preview-as.html see this one they have done this

Comment: See the comments under that article, many people have said its not working.

Comment: ok then is there any way to do that **I want to capture a image with out opening a camera application and without previewing it **

Comment: You can capture an image without opening camera application i.e. with Camera object but in that case if you don't want to view the preview you can put a layer (like e.g. an ImageView) on top of the preview surface.